# Integer type cast issue

Tags: php, arrays

`CASE # 1:` I have the following code which outputs the correct number

```
<?php 
   $integer = 10000000000;
   $array = array($integer);
   print_r($array[0]); //output = 1000000000
?>
```

`CASE # 2:` But when i explicitly type cast the same number to integer it gives different output

```
<?php
    $integer = (int)10000000000;
    $array = array($integer);
    print_r($array[0]); //output = 1410065408
?>
```

`CASE # 3:` If i make the number smaller by one 0 and type cast it, then it returns the correct number

```
<?php
   $integer = (int)1000000000;
   $array = array($integer);
   print_r($array[0]); //output = 1000000000
?>
```

Why it is not producing the correct output in `CASE # 2`?

Comment: Looks like you've exceeded the limit for the Integer type. The max value of an integer is 2147483647. Read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Yeah, you've exceeded the limit for the Integer type, so it converts to the maximum integer known.

Comment: It should be noted that the first case "works" because PHP auto-converts it to a string (Or some type that can handle the number).

Comment: On a 32 bit system the integer type is 2 bytes on a 64 bit system is 4 bytes. In your case it depends on your build of php

Comment: In your answer you explain that when you remove one 0 everything works fine so in that case your system can handle 4 byte integers, and you are exceeding the limit with 2 bits so i suggest you use float instead of integer, wich should support up to 8 bytes

Comment: Yes i used the `float` and it output the correct value. Thanks! for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely exceeding max value of int on your platform.

From the [**Official PHP Doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). Integer size can be 
>   determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using
>   the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

**For 32-bit platforms:**

Integers can be from -2147483648 to 2147483647

**For 64-bit platforms:**

Integers can be from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Comment: Yup that makes sense now. I used `float` instead and it output the correct number. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the maximum size of an integer in your second example. In your first example, PHP automagically uses a larger numeric data type such as `float` to hold the variable because it is too big for an int. When you explicitly cast it to an `int` in example 2, because it is bigger than the max size it truncates it to that maximum size. In example 3 the number is short enough to contained in an `int`. If you try casting it to a `float` it will produce the correct result.

```
<?php
    $integer = (float)10000000000;
    $array = array($integer);
    print_r($array[0]); //output = 10000000000
?>
```

The constant `PHP_INT_SIZE` will tell you what the maximum supported `int` size on your php installation is.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of an integer is platform dependent, but it's around 2 billion. CASE #2 is 10 billion.

If you want to typecast use a float, it has a much higher limit...

**Reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php